# How to align address block and date with signature?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, letters

I need to have the address and date aligned with the signature headers, like with the semi-block header type, but the address block is located all the way to the right of the page while the signature is in the middle. My document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{letter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\address{0000 Easy Street,\\
Nowhere, CA 00000}

\signature{Joe Schmoe}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Somewhere}

\opening{Dear blah..:}

Blah blah blah blah blah.

\closing{Sincerely,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

I have tried inserting negative space in front of each line of the address, via `\hspace`, but that only moved the address.

I have also looked at using `\longindentation` to move the signature all the way to the right, but that isn't the result I want.

How can I move the address so that it aligns with the signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is to align the address to the signature, as it relies only on the spacing to the left of the two structures:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{letter}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\opening}% <cmd>
  {\raggedleft\begin}% <search>
  {\hspace*{\dimexpr\longindentation-\tabcolsep}\begin}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>


\address{0000 Easy Street,\\
Nowhere, CA 00000}

\signature{Joe Schmoe}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Somewhere}

\opening{Dear blah..:}

Blah blah blah blah blah.

\closing{Sincerely,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Above I've patched `\opening` to insert a gap equivalent to that of the `\closing` macro, minus the `\tabcolsep` inserted by `\opening` as it sets the address and date in a `tabular`.

---

Of course, it is just as easy to replicate the `letter` class inside the default `article` class, which allows you far greater freedom when trying to position and adjust things:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\hspace*{.5\textwidth}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  0000 Easy Street, \\
  Nowhere, CA 00000 \\ \\
  \today
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Somewhere

\bigskip

Dear blah..:

\medskip

Blah blah blah blah blah.

\bigskip

\hspace*{.5\textwidth}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  Sincerely, \\[4\normalbaselineskip]
  Joe Schmoe
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```